Merge multiple Kiebase files
I have multiple knowledge base file generated in drools. Each file contains different number of rules.

Assuming if am having 3 file using the filepath i can convert each file into kiebase object.
Code :
    DroolsObjectInputStream in = new DroolsObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath1));
            KieBase kbTemp1 = (KieBase) in.readObject();
            in.close();

DroolsObjectInputStream in = new DroolsObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath2));
            KieBase kbTemp2 = (KieBase) in.readObject();
            in.close();

DroolsObjectInputStream in = new DroolsObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath3));
            KieBase kbTemp3 = (KieBase) in.readObject();
            in.close();

The problem am facing is am not able find the option create a single kieBase object (combine all the kiebase into single kiebase object) so i can directly create a StatelessKieSession and use execute. Right now because i have 3 kieBase i have create different statelesssession and call execute multiple times.
Am using the Kiebase in the following way:
StatelessKieSession stateless1= kbTemp1 .newStatelessKieSession();
stateless1.execute(input);

StatelessKieSession stateless2= kbTemp2 .newStatelessKieSession();
stateless2.execute(input);

Kindly let me know if any option is available to combine all the individual kiebase to single one.
Using Drools : 7.73.0

How did you end up with three separate files in the first place? Seems like that's where you should be fixing the issue.

We have around 40 K rule which need to be loaded. Our application is hosted on AWS lambda which is having a API gateway timeout of 30 seconds. So we have breaking the rule into manageable chunk records and multiple files are getting generated. Now at last we need to Merge the file or load the files parallelly one by one into kiebase.

Did you try pre-compiling your rules instead? When I had a single KieBase larger than that, this is how I got my rules loaded (significantly decreases actual loading time too.)

For us the rules are dynamics and keeps on changing. Hence we dynamically generate and load each time. Could you also kindly share any link for can pre compiling the rule for this case ?
